# cookies not being set in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm running into a problem with setting a value for a cookie. Everytime I run the function I made, it is always coming back with undefined for the cookie value. Here is my code:

login.html -

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();

    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();

    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

$('#submit').click(function() {
    if ($('#username').val() != "" && $('#password').val() != "") {
        // set the cookie 
        // and redirect
        setCookie("username", $('#username').val(), 365);

        window.location = "profile.html";
    } else {
        alert("All fields must be filled out");
    }
});
```

and on the profile.html page:

```
function getCookie(cookie_name) {
    var name = cookie_name + "=";

    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

    for (var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
         var c = ca[i];

         while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);

         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);   
    }
   return ""; 
}


function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");

    if (user != "") {
        $('#user_greet').html("<b>Welcome " + user + "</b>");   
    } else {
       alert("You are not allowed to be here");
        window.location = "login.html"; 
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   checkCookie();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It works for me. Is your click handler inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Yes. It should be `(document).ready(function() { $("#submit").click... })`

Comment: On the profile.html page it keeps redirecting me back to the login page.

Comment: nevermind, it was my cookie cache. Thanks, it works now!